# Wysiwyg image upload not working

Tags: magento-1.7, wysiwyg

First I should say that there are many questions and answers on this topic around the web but I'm not finding anything close to what's happening here so I really hope someone here is able to help.

I have the wysiwyg disabled by default and when I click on Insert Image the pop up comes up as expected but is not fully rendered, see attached screen shot.

The console is saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, see attached screen shot.

[image: Image Upload dialogue window]

[image: Console error]

[image: Prototype js error]

I have disabled all extensions to rule out conflict + both media and wysiwyg folders have 777 permissions.

EDIT: I have tested Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac + Chrome on PC, all with the same result.

Just let me know if I left out any necessary info!

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

So after a day of diving into this issue; disabling modules, enabling modules, removing changes in local etc etc, I found the problem.

I used an extension called PhPro_Translate to do a large amount of translations for front and backend from English to Swedish and so in my std install I have just inserted all the rows of translations into core_translate (as the extension does). It turns out that one of the 80 or so translated strings under the Mage_Cms module cause the error. I honestly did not have the energy to look into exactly which string as I still have 3400 rows working :), but I have a vague idea it could have been a Swedish word with umlauts.

In the very unlikely event that someone else runs into the same problem, that's the answer!

Cheerio

UPDATE: Since this could have implications in other contexts, here's what caused the js error. In one of the translations I had used single quotes around a word to denote it was the original English term but I had forgotten to escape the quotes. Voilà!